# How to use 'curvefit' in python to fit a neural network?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, transformer-model

```
model = torch.load(.. / .....)

def fit_func(input_param, *params):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        # predict flux using the neural network, params is the values need to be fitted.
        predicted_flux = model(params)
    return predicted_flux.cpu().detach().numpy()

# true parameters and true flux in the dataset
parameters, true_flux = get_input_flux(input_valid, flux_valid)

for i in range(len(validation_set)):
    initial_guess = parameters[i, :]  # use true parameters as initial values
    estimated_params, _, _, mesg, ier = curve_fit(
        fit_func,
        xdata=np.arange(len(flux[i, :])),
        ydata=flux[i, :],
        p0=initial_guess,
        bounds=(-1.5, 1.5),
        method='dogbox',
        full_output=True,
        xtol=1e-10, ftol=1e-10,
        max_nfev=100000
    )
    print(i, mesg, ier, estimated_params[0], estimated_params[1], estimated_params[2])
```

The function of the neural network is to input parameters and output fluxes. I am trying to use the trained best neural network model to fit the parameters. However, I always obtain results same as the initial values.

Comment: What is the `full_output` you get ?

Comment: Hi @jlandercy, the `mesg` is ' `xtol` termination condition is satisfied.' `ier` equals to 3. And the fitted values are near the initial values.

Comment: If I use `method='lm'`, the `mesg` and `ier` are `The relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most 0.000000` and `2`.

Comment: It seems the initial parameters you provided are already in a loss minimum, hence no further local optimization. Do you expect the parameters to be different for the optimum? Without being able to reproduce your issue (dataset and trained model) it is impossible to tell. Anyway, if you have reason to expect optimum elsewhere on the parameters space you probably want to change your initial guess or use a global minimum search first to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply @jlandercy! I would like to try a global minimum algorithm to find the optimal values. Could you please recommend some global minimum algorithms? I have no idea about it.

Comment: The number of parameters I need to fit is 38. So maybe this fitting problem is a little bit complex?